# KeePass does not offer `Open with Google Chrome`

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, keepass

I'm using `KeePass` and `Google Chrome` (not plug-ins) for quite some time.

I have reinstalled my operating system (`Windows 7`) and both `KeePass` and `Google Chrome` and since then, when I right-click an entry and chose `URL` I don't have the `Open with Google Chrome` option - only internet explorer is available.

Seems like `KeePass` did not recognize `Chrome` - any idea how to fix it?

I re-installed `KeePass` but did not reinstall `Chrome` yet.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall Chrome, then set it as the default system browser instead of IE. That should hopefully do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's still not available via the context menu, but you can change the URL to include the `cmd:{GOOGLECHROME}` prefix as described in the [KeePass online help](https://keepass.info/help/base/autourl.html#subst).

For example you can use [`cmd://{GOOGLECHROME} "https://www.example.com/"`](https://keepass.info/help/base/autourl.html#subst).